# Type 'System.Configuration.IgnoreSection, System.Configuration' not found on Mono

Tags: c#, mono

I have some very simple code that is meant to iterate through the sections of my config file on Mono, the problem line is:

```
foreach (ConfigurationSection section in config.Sections)
{
    // etc.
}
```

This code runs fine in dev and on other servers, but on this new server throws an exception:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Type 'System.Configuration.IgnoreSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' not found.
```

I'm running Mono on an Ubuntu 14.0.4 LTS server. Running `mono -V` gives:

```
Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1.1)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
TLS:           __thread
SIGSEGV:       altstack
Notifications: epoll
Architecture:  amd64
Disabled:      none
Misc:          softdebug 
LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
GC:            sgen
```

Any help would be appreciated.

For the record, the full stack trace of the exception is:

```
at System.Configuration.InternalConfigurationHost.GetConfigType (System.String typeName, Boolean throwOnError) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Configuration.ConfigInfo.CreateInstance () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Configuration.SectionInfo.CreateInstance () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Configuration.Configuration.GetSectionInstance (System.Configuration.SectionInfo config, Boolean createDefaultInstance) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionCollection.get_Item (System.String name) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionCollection+<GetEnumerator>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Cuscus.API.Settings+<GetValue>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 (System.Configuration.Configuration config, System.String settingskey) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at ...
```

Comment: Hey, im stuck with the same problem on a debian VM. Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: Mono 3.* are years old and make sure you first move to Mono 4.x, http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin

Comment: Upgrading to Mono 4.x did the trick. When I'd first installed Mono I hadn't followed the instructions properly, just did `apt-get install mono-complete` before adding the source.